# Vue init webpack test - not creating project - strict mode error?

Tags: bash, webpack, vue.js

I have tried to create a project using

```
$ vue init webpack test
```

and  got following error

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init:60 let template =
>   program.args[0]
>             ^ SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet  supported outside strict mode at
>   exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16) at Module._compile
>   (module.js:374:25) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:344:32) at Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:301:12) at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10) at
>   startup (node.js:136:18) at node.js:966:3

Unfortunatly, "test" directory is not created.

I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10 and the following NPM packages:

- vue@2.5.2
- vue-cli@2.9.1
- node.js@0.0.0
- npm 3.5.2

Comment: node.js@0.0.0??? There is an issue quite similar to yours, at [vue-cli on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/618). You seem to be using an older NodeJS version. Whats your output for `node --version`?

Comment: node --version = v4.2.6

Comment: upgraded NodeJS version to v8.8.1 using sudo n stable - problem solved - thank you for the assistance

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps node verison is too low.
update your node version using

```
npm install -g n 
sudo n stable  
sudo npm install npm -g
```

when you node -v find there is no change, but try to init vue project again.